# In app purchasing and mobile topups

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am looking to develop a mobile app that provides prepaid wireless refills or top-ups.  Since there is no shipping would this be considered a virtual product.  If so, considering the markup on an airtime pin is only around, 12% how could I offer purchases through the app if Google wants 30%?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jibril

Answer (score 0):

You should not use google or apply in app purchases, instead you should use a 3rd party payment processor to avoid their high fees. I would suggest stripe or braintree. Reloadly also makes it very easy to app mobile top ups to your app,you can view their API docs here https://topupsapi.docs.apiary.io/#

Reloadly can also provide the UI framework and code samples for your app